# Iterative method for finding real solutions to $a+b+c+d = abcd = 7.11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I have "come up with" a method for finding $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$ such that their sum and product is equal and wanted to ask if the method is sound.

First, rearrange both equations so that only $a, b$ and $c$ are on the LHS and $d$ is on the RHS. That is,

\begin{align}
a+b+c &= 7.11 - d\\
abc &= \frac{7.11}{d}.
\end{align}

We then explicitly require that $a+b+c = abc$ and as such that $7.11 - d = \frac{7.11}{d}$. This gives us a quadratic in $d$, which we can solve (giving $1.2038$), this is fed back into the expression to give us

\begin{align}
a+b+c &= 5.9062\\
abc &= 5.9062.
\end{align}

We repeat until only $a$ is left on the LHS and hence have $4$ real numbers whose sum and product are equal.

> Is there any reason to believe that the solutions are unique (up to permutation)?

Comment: Your problem is symmetric in the four variables, so any solution will only be unique up to a permutation of the variables.

Comment: Indeed, this isn't an issue but I forgot to mention it in the question! Up to permutation of the variables, is there any reason to believe the solutions are unique?

Answer (score 1):

No, the solution will not be unique.  You have two equations in four unknowns, so you expect a two dimensional space of solutions.  The original puzzle required that the variables be exact multiples of $0.01$ as it involved cash-four items bought with the sum and product of the prices $7.11$.  The intended answer is $3.16, 1.25, 1.50, 1.20$, which is different from yours.  There is no reason to expect that $a+b+c=abc$.  What you have done is essentially choose values for $d$ and $c$, which fortunately are in the solution space, then solved for $a$ and $b$ using the equations.

Comment: "The original puzzle" is not what I'm looking at. I'm looking at an iterative method to find solutions to a system like the one given above. If I "choose" values at each step, I either get complex solutions or real solutions. I'm only interested in looking at real solutions. Nothing in my question alludes to the problem you are talking about, which is easy to solve via brute force

Comment: The intended answer is enough to show that your solution is not unique.  One could trace out a region of the $c,d$ plane in which the solutions for $a,b$ are real.  I thought I answered the question you asked.  My reason for bringing up the original puzzle was that the condition that all variables be multiples of $0.01$ was enough to make a unique solution.